# Android Cannot access accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-logcat

in my android application it does not seem to let me use the accelerometer. when i call it in a statement the application crashes.  the statement that seems to be causing the crash is:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

The application is simple as is only calls the accelerometer and runs when this statement is absent, the above statment is called before the onCreate method and the log cat is below

```
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.b00348312.workout/com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutAppActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3526)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutAppActivity.<init>(WorkoutAppActivity.java:25)   
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021) 
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-24 20:08:46.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     ... 11 more
```

from the logcat i cannot figure out the cause of this problem when this statement worked in a different programme.

Comment: full tutorial on using accelerometer data in android application http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a double negative? lol Cut the code where ure calling the system service and paste inside your onCreate

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

//PLACE YOUR ACCEL CODE IN HERE       

    }
```

Comment: but i have an method outside of the onCreate which uses the accelerometer. what should i do for that

Comment: leave it where it is, you just need to initiate the sensor in the onCreate

Answer (score 0):

You have to grab the SensorManager after onCreate is called.

"System services not available to Activities before onCreate()"

Comment: so calling it before the onCreate is ok as long as i use it within the oncreate?